# Best way to store passwords across devices?

Tags: password-management, account-security

KeePass is not good. It would work perfectly if all I wanted my passwords for were accounts on my computer, but if I needed to log in to Netflix on my TV, or my Facebook at a friend's house, I'm out of luck.

We're constantly reminded to keep our passwords secure and safe, so can someone please advise as to what the best way to store passwords is?

Encrypted sure, but I'm looking for a solution like KeePass that works across all of my devices, one that is not limited to the scope of the specific device the KeePass is on.

Comment: Why are you out of luck? You need to be able to log into Netflix or Facebook even when you don't have access to your KeePass database? Or you're too lazy to type in 16 characters? Basically, can you be more specific about what real life problem KeePass doesn't solve? Otherwise this will get closed as a rant.

Comment: Let me correct your entire scenario: "Storing the KeePass file on my local computer is not convenient when I need to access those passwords when I am not at my computer." The solution is simple: store the password file on your mobile or use a cloud solution (like KeePass offers).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a solution like KeePass that works across all of my devices

Keepass (specifically the Keepass2Android app) has a range of built-in ways to synchronize your database across devices.

I use the Google Drive option and it's been working great for me for the past year to sync keepass between my phone and my various computers.

[image: Keepass list of storage types]

Answer (score -4):

steghide is an application able to hide data in image or audio files. Not sure if the application is compatible with Mac/Windows/Chrome OS.

I envision downloading close to 100 images, keep them in a single folder, then choosing my favorite image to hide my password in. If using your friend's system to watch Netflix, store these images - several random ones already hidden with your passwords - on a password encrypted flashdrive (in case you lose it), so whenever you need your passwords, you have them hidden in pictures, on an encrypted flash drive.

http://steghide.sourceforge.net

Comment: This is known as "Security by obscurity" and is not secure on its own. I'm curious, if you propose using an encrypted flash drive (which is not compatible across all devices) why not suggest storing the KeePass file on the flash drive instead of this made-up approach?